# Column element that has been overflow to the second column in Css

Tags: html, css, layout, frontend

everyone, I have a problem using the column attribute as the height of the 1 column element that has been overflow to the second column.

[image]

[image]

Am I missing some thing ?

Many thanks for any helps

Comment: Would a min height on the image element do the trick?

Comment: elements have different height sizes so I don't set a min-height for any of them

Answer (score 0):

if image width is not problem for you then set it as a fixed value it will help you to solve this issue.